# How can I reduce the size of downloaded file?

Tags: cognito-forms

I couldn't send downloaded file to my colleagues through Office 365 because of large size. I need an auto compress function before downloading entire file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

We do not offer the ability to compress files that are uploaded to Cognito Forms. The files that are uploaded are not altered and are intended to be downloaded as needed via the Entries page.